# Can I get a different UID than EUID and GID than EGID in a command?

Tags: c, bash, process, uid

I have a program that gets its own UID, EUID, GID, EGID, and I want to get UID!=EUID and GID!=EGID.

I've tried changing the owner and group of the program file, but I'm always getting the same results.

Here is the c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cad[128];

    pid_t pid;
    pid = getpid();

    char s1[] = "ps -p ";
    char s2[] = " -o cmd,pid,ppid,uid,euid,gid,egid,pri,stat";
    char spid[42];
    sprintf(spid, "%d", (int)pid);
    char result[2048];

    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, spid);
    strcat(result, s2);

    sprintf(cad,"Program %s started.\n",argv[0]);
    write(1,cad,strlen(cad));

    system(result);

    read(0,cad,1);

    sprintf(cad,"Program %s ended.\n",argv[0]);
    write(1,cad,strlen(cad));

    exit(0);
}
```

The commands I've tried are:

```
$ sudo chown 2000 filename
$ sudo chgrp 2000 filename
$ sudo chmod u+r,g+x filename
```

And then executing the compiled program. Always getting:

```
Program ./pgm1_1_1 started.
CMD                           PID  PPID   UID  EUID   GID  EGID PRI STAT
./pgm1_1_1                  18216 17683  1000  1000  1000  1000  19 S+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not set the SUID and SGID bits in the permissions:

```
sudo chmod ug+s filename
```

Or, doing the permissions setting all in one, you can use either of these:

```
sudo chmod 6755 filename              # Numeric permissions (octal)
sudo chmod a=rx,u+w,ug+s filename     # Symbolic permissions
```

You should run `ls -l filename` after you've finished the permissions setting.   With the SUID and SGID bits set, you should see something like:

```
-rwsr-sr-x  1 2000  2000  8712 May  8 00:18 filename
```

where the two `s` values are crucial in the permissions.  You might have names where I get to see the UID and GID numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can see the changes, but I still getting same UID than EUID and GID than EGID, and I want to get values UID != EUID and GID != EGID. I'm missing some concepts I guess. Where can I spot that?

Comment: This is where things start to get tricky.  Is the file system mounted with options such as ’no setuid’, I wonder? That would account for not seeing any effect.

Comment: It is mounted with 'no suid' option. Is that the problem? How can I solve that? Thank you a lot, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The ’no suid’ mount option is the problem, yes.  Workaround A include putting the program on a file system that doesn't have the ’no suid’ option set (the root or `/` file system is probably like that), or remounting the file system without the ’no suid’ option.  The latter may require editing a config file in the `/etc` directory; make a backup of the file before you back it.